# Docker display issues in interactive terminal mode

Tags: ubuntu, docker

We have docker running on couple of ubuntu machines. When we try to run it in interactive shell mode, we face some weird behavior. Terminal has fixed size and long string input results in overwriting it cyclically. Here's what it looks like:

```
user@e8800fc208de:/$ 
fffffffffffc208de:/$ fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

mc also has fixed size. It seems that it depends on host system. We also have a couple of machines running arch, and docker works as we expect it to there.

Current docker version is 17.06. 17.03 demonstrates exactly the same behavior. Host machines run ubuntu 14.04 and ubuntu 16.04. 
And flags we run it with are: `--rm -it`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have similar experience when I used Docker CE 17.05 or 17.06 Edge version and there was a bug that line feed(line break) isn't properly attached. IIRC it has fixed in 17.06.0-ce-rc2 or something. Try with later version. Current latest one as of now is 17.09.0-ce-rc1-mac28 (19152) in Mac OS.

Comment: The very last version I was able to find is 17.07 and this issue remains there.

Comment: Ok. I've found 17.09.0-ce-rc1. Still nothing seems to be fixed.